# Table printing a list of lists Common lisp

Tags: printing, common-lisp

I wish to print this data in a table with the columns aligned. I tried with `Format` but the columns were not aligned. Does anyone know how to do it ? Thank you.

```
(("tiscali" 10000 2.31 0.84 -14700.0 "none")
 ("atlantia" 50 22.65 22.68 1.5 "none")
 ("bper-banca" 1000 1.59 2.01 423.0 "none")
 ("alerion-cleanpower" 30 44.14 36.45 -230.7   "none")
 ("tesmec" 10000 0.12 0.14 150.0 "none")
 ("cover-50" 120 8.95 9.6 78.0 "none")
 ("ovs" 1000 1.71 1.93 217.0 "none")
 ("credito-emiliano" 200 5.7 6.26 112.0 "none"))
```

I tried to align the columns wit the ~T directive, no way. Is there a piece of code that prints nicely table data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down.

First, let's give your data a nice name:

```
(defparameter *data* 
    '(("tiscali" 10000 2.31 0.84 -14700.0 "none")
      ("atlantia" 50 22.65 22.68 1.5 "none")
      ("bper-banca" 1000 1.59 2.01 423.0 "none")
      ("alerion-cleanpower" 30 44.14 36.45 -230.7   "none")
      ("tesmec" 10000 0.12 0.14 150.0 "none")
      ("cover-50" 120 8.95 9.6 78.0 "none")
      ("ovs" 1000 1.71 1.93 217.0 "none")
      ("credito-emiliano" 200 5.7 6.26 112.0 "none")))
```

Now, come up with a way to print each line using [`format`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_(Common_Lisp)) and `destructuring-bind`. Widths of various fields are hard-coded in.

```
(defun print-line (line)
    (destructuring-bind (a b c d e f) line
        (format T "~20a ~5d ~6,2f ~6,2f ~10,2f ~4a~%"  a b c d e f)))
```

Once you know you can print *a* line, you just need to do that for *each* line.

```
(mapcar 'print-line *data*)
```

Result:

```
tiscali              10000   2.31   0.84  -14700.00 none
atlantia                50  22.65  22.68       1.50 none
bper-banca            1000   1.59   2.01     423.00 none
alerion-cleanpower      30  44.14  36.45    -230.70 none
tesmec               10000   0.12   0.14     150.00 none
cover-50               120   8.95   9.60      78.00 none
ovs                   1000   1.71   1.93     217.00 none
credito-emiliano       200   5.70   6.26     112.00 none
```

Comment: Hello Chris , I cannot repeat your result. 
*DATA*  LISA-USER(26): (mapcar #'print-line *data*)
tiscali              10000   2.31   0.84  -14700.00 none
atlantia                50  22.65  22.68       1.50 none
bper-banca            1000   1.59   2.01     423.00 none
alerion-cleanpower      30  44.14  36.45    -230.70 none
tesmec               10000   0.12   0.14     150.00 none
cover-50               120   8.95   9.60      78.00 none
ovs                   1000   1.71   1.93     217.00 none
credito-emiliano       200   5.70   6.26     112.00 none
(NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL NIL)
???

Comment: Sorry formatting is not shown in the comment. Columns are not aligned.

Comment: Field width values _are_ hard-coded in in the code I've shown. If your data varies from that shown, your columns might not align.

Comment: The data are identical. I copied and pasted your code and data. There should be some system dependent item that I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this in my personal code, that I reproduced here in a simplified way:

```
(defpackage :tabular (:use :cl))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
(in-package :tabular)
```

I have a function that turns any object into a list of values (a row), here the usage is for a list of values, so it is already in the correct shape.

```
(defgeneric columnize (object)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  (:documentation "Representation of object as a list of fields")                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  (:method ((o list)) o))
```

I also define a `transpose` method that works with lists of various sizes:

```
(defun transpose (lists)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  (when (notany #'null lists)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    (cons                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
     (mapcar #'first lists)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
     (transpose (mapcar #'cdr lists)))))
```

Here is your data, as defined by Chris:

```
(defparameter *data*                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  '(("tiscali" 10000 2.31 0.84 -14700.0 "none")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    ("atlantia" 50 22.65 22.68 1.5 "none")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    ("bper-banca" 1000 1.59 2.01 423.0 "none")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    ("alerion-cleanpower" 30 44.14 36.45 -230.7   "none")                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    ("tesmec" 10000 0.12 0.14 150.0 "none")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    ("cover-50" 120 8.95 9.6 78.0 "none")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    ("ovs" 1000 1.71 1.93 217.0 "none")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    ("credito-emiliano" 200 5.7 6.26 112.0 "none")))
```

And finally, a function that prints a list of objects in a tabular way.
Basically, I convert all objects to list of values, convert them to string, and compute their size. This gives a matrix of size that I transpose to have a list of sizes for the same column: this is used to compute the width of each column, based on the maximum size of the actual data.

In practice, I allow also the generic function to add indicators like how to justify (left/right), etc.

```
(defun tabulate (stream objects)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  (loop                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    for n from 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    for o in objects                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    for row = (mapcar #'princ-to-string (columnize o))                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    collect row into rows                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    collect (mapcar #'length row) into row-widths                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    finally                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
       (flet ((build-format-arguments (max-width row)                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                (when (> max-width 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                  (list max-width #\space row))))                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
         (loop                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
           with number-width = (ceiling (log n 10))                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
           with col-widths = (transpose row-widths)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
           with max-col-widths = (mapcar (lambda (s) (reduce #'max s)) col-widths)                                                                                                                                                                                              
           for index from 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
           for row in rows                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
           for entries = (mapcan #'build-format-arguments max-col-widths row)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
           do (format stream                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                     "~v,'0d. ~{~v,,,va~^ ~}~%"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                     number-width index entries)))))
```

For example:

```
(fresh-line)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
(tabulate *standard-output* *data*)
```

Gives:

```
0. tiscali            10000 2.31  0.84  -14700.0 none                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
1. atlantia           50    22.65 22.68 1.5      none                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
2. bper-banca         1000  1.59  2.01  423.0    none                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
3. alerion-cleanpower 30    44.14 36.45 -230.7   none                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
4. tesmec             10000 0.12  0.14  150.0    none                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
5. cover-50           120   8.95  9.6   78.0     none                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
6. ovs                1000  1.71  1.93  217.0    none                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
7. credito-emiliano   200   5.7   6.26  112.0    none
```

As you can see there is some adjustments that could be made to format floating points values so that they align on the dot, but this is already quite useful.

Comment: Hello coredump what I get using your code Is 0. tiscali            10000 2.31  0.84  -14700.0 none
1. atlantia           50    22.65 22.68 1.5      none
2. bper-banca         1000  1.59  2.01  423.0    none
3. alerion-cleanpower 30    44.14 36.45 -230.7   none
4. tesmec             10000 0.12  0.14  150.0    none
5. cover-50           120   8.95  9.6   78.0     none
6. ovs                1000  1.71  1.93  217.0    none
7. credito-emiliano   200   5.7   6.26  112.0    none I have the idea that the single tab is different for blank spaces and characters. Does this make sense to you ?